# Update Order Status action missing

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Having an issue where the "Update Order Status..." menu option is not available on order list pages. This is true both for admins and for users who have permissions set to manage commerce orders. Any ideas as to what might cause this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. Please submit a issue at http://github.com/craftcms/commerce